# Cauchy convergence in L2 of empirical CDF implies convergence in probability to a tail sigma-algebra measurable function

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables

I am reading the proof of de Finetti's theorem in Chow and Teicher's book *Probability Theory* and there is one claim which I am not sure about. Let me quote some context first:

> Theorem: Random variables $X_n, n \ge 1$ on $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ are interchangeable iff they are conditionally independent and identically distributed given some $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{G}$ of events. Moreover, $\mathcal{G}$ can be taken to be either the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{E}$  of permutable events or the tail $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{T}$, and $\mathbb{P}(X_1 < x_1 \mid \mathcal{E}) = \mathbb{P}(X_1 < x_1 \mid \mathcal{T})$ a.s..
>
> Proof: Sufficiency is immediate since ... . Apropos of necessity, for $n \ge 1$ and any real $x$, define $$\xi_n(x) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n I_{\{X_i < x\}}$$ Then $$\mathbb{E} [\xi_n(x) - \xi_m(x)]^2 = \frac{|m-n|}{mn} \left( \mathbb{P}(X_1 < x) - \mathbb{P}(X_1 < x, X_2 < x) \right) \to 0 \tag{1}$$ as $m,n \to \infty$, **whence $\xi_n(x) \stackrel{p}{\to}$ some $\mathcal{T}$-measurable r.v. $\xi(x)$.**

I know that since $L^2$ is complete, (1) implies $L^2$ convergence of the sequence $\{\xi_n(x)\}$, which in turn implies convergence in probability to $\xi(x)$, say.

**Why is $\xi(x)$  $\mathcal{T}$-measurable?**

It intuitively makes sense to me but how do I show this formally? I'll need to show that $\{\xi(x) < t\} \in \sigma(\xi_{m+1}(x), \xi_{m+2}(x), \ldots)$ for every $t \in \mathbb{R}$ and $m \ge 1$. Now convergence in probability implies convergence in distribution, which in turn implies $\lim_{n} \{\xi_n(x) < t\} = \{\xi(x) < t\}$. But $\lim_{n} \{\xi_n(x) < t\} = \lim_n \left\{\frac{1}{n-m} \sum_{i=m+1}^n I_{\{X_i < x\}} < t\right\} \in \sigma(\xi_{m+1}(x), \xi_{m+2}(x), \ldots)$. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convergence in probability implies that a subsequence $\xi_{n(k)}$ converges almost surely and it is very standard that this implies measurability.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_in_measure